# This Should-Be-Simple SQL Query Is Driving Me Mad

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, variance

I am working on a SQL Query that should be simple(ish) in theory, but it's proving to be a challenge for me.

Using the current Stored Procedure as a Template, all I need to do is add in the Variance of what is returned as the Total Received.  I've created the Local Table and input the amounts within that Table that the Total Received should subtract from in order to create the Variance.

But every time I run this, the numbers return incorrectly and also return multiple times.

Essentially I simply need to be able to return the Total Received of each Fund and subtract it from its Goal (the Local Table) and that's the Variance.  I do NOT need the Constituent Details, only the Fund Details.

Here is the Stored Procedure I am working from:

```
 (
    @trans_start_dt datetime = NULL,
    @trans_end_dt datetime = NULL,
    @fund_str varchar(4000) = null,
    @fyear_str varchar(4000) = null,
    @campaign_str varchar(4000) = null,
    @designation_str varchar(4000) = null,
    @appeal_str varchar(4000) = null,
    @mode int = 1,      -- now default to Fund
    @show_constituent_detail char(1) = 'N',
    @list_no int,
    @list_acts_upon int = 1,
    @channel_str varchar(4000) = null,
    @cont_start_dt datetime = null,
    @cont_end_dt datetime = null,
    @posting_start_dt datetime = null,
    @posting_end_dt datetime = null
    )
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
/*******************************************************************************
Combines into a single report procedure that works with a single datawindow.

Additional parameters @designation_str, @fyear_str and @campaign_str added for additional filtering.

New modes group by Campaign or FYear. New report moves "Constituent" mode out of the @mode parameter and into "Show Constituent Detail".  The legacy mode "Constituent" can be run using Mode 1 (Fund) and Show Constituent Detail = 'Y'.

Note:  Former mode "Constituent" is now achieved by using Mode = Fund and Show Constituent Detail = 'Yes'.


Modes
    1 Fund
    3 Payment
    4 Campaign, Fund
    5 Campaign, Fund, Designation

Exec [dbo].[RP_FUND_ACTIVITY_REPORT] 
    @trans_start_dt = '2000-01-01',
    @trans_end_dt = '2011-01-01',
    @fund_str = null,
    @fyear_str = null,
    @campaign_str = null,
    @designation_str = null,
    @appeal_str = null,
    @mode = 3,
    @list_no = null,
    @channel_str = null

***************************************************************************************/
Set Transaction Isolation Level Read Uncommitted

If @mode = 2
  Begin
    Raiserror('Group By mode Constituent (2) is no longer supported.  Use group by Fund, and set Show Constituent Detail to Yes.', 11, 2)   
    RETURN
  End

If @mode not in (1,3,4,5)
  Begin
    Raiserror('Mode %i is not a valid setting.', 11, 2, @mode)  
    RETURN
  End

If @list_no is NOT NULL and not Exists (Select * From dbo.VS_LIST Where list_no = @list_no)
  Begin
    Raiserror('List number %i is not a valid list.', 11, 2, @list_no)   
    RETURN
  End

If (@posting_start_dt is NULL and @posting_end_dt is NOT NULL)
    or (@posting_start_dt is NOT NULL and @posting_end_dt is NULL)
  Begin
    Raiserror('Posting Start and End dates must both have a value if used.', 11, 2) 
    RETURN
  End

Declare @filter_by_posting_date bit

If @posting_start_dt is NOT NULL and @posting_end_dt is NOT NULL
    Select @filter_by_posting_date = 1
Else
    Select @filter_by_posting_date = 0

Declare @fund Table (fund_no int, fund_desc varchar(30) null)
Declare @channel Table(id int, description varchar(30) null)
Declare @appeal Table(appeal_no int, fund_desc varchar(30) null)
Declare @cont_designation Table (id int, description varchar(30) null)

IF @fund_str is null or Coalesce(Datalength(ltrim(@fund_str)),0) = 0
    Insert  into @fund (fund_no, fund_desc)
    Select  fund_no, description
    From    [dbo].vs_fund
Else
    Insert  into @fund (fund_no, fund_desc)
    Select  fund_no, description
    from    [dbo].vs_fund
    where   charindex(',' + convert(varchar, fund_no) + ',' , ',' + @fund_str + ',') > 0

IF @channel_str is null or Coalesce(Datalength(ltrim(@channel_str)),0) = 0
    Insert  into @channel
    Select  id, description
    From    [dbo].tr_sales_channel
Else
    Insert  into @channel
    Select  id, description
    from    [dbo].tr_sales_channel
    where   charindex(',' + convert(varchar, id) + ',' , ',' + @channel_str + ',') > 0


IF @appeal_str is null or Coalesce(Datalength(ltrim(@appeal_str)),0) = 0
    Insert  into @appeal
    Select  appeal_no, description
    From    [dbo].t_appeal
Else
    Insert  into @appeal
    Select  appeal_no, description
    from    [dbo].t_appeal
    where   charindex(',' + convert(varchar, appeal_no) + ',' , ',' + @appeal_str + ',') > 0


IF @designation_str is null or Coalesce(Datalength(ltrim(@designation_str)),0) = 0
  Begin
    Insert into @cont_designation (id, description)
    Values (0, '(none)')

    Insert  into @cont_designation(id, description)
    Select  id, description
    From    [dbo].TR_CONT_DESIGNATION
  End
Else
    Insert  into @cont_designation(id, description)
    Select  id, description
    from    [dbo].TR_CONT_DESIGNATION
    where   charindex(',' + convert(varchar, id) + ',' , ',' + @designation_str + ',') > 0

Create  table  #transactions(
    sequence_no int null, 
    trn_type int null,
    fund_no int null,
    fyear int null,
    campaign_no int null,
    campaign varchar(30) null,
    cont_designation_id int,
    batch_no int null,
    posted_ind bit,
    ref_no int null,
    cont_dt datetime null,
    trn_dt datetime null,
    pledge money null,
    pledge_payment money null,
    gift money null,
    restricted money null,
    write_off money null,
    total_received money null,
    channel int null,
    customer_no int null,
    pmt_method_id int null,
    pmt_method varchar(30) null,
    pledge_pmt_amt money null,
    gift_pmt_amt money null,
    creditee_type int null, 
    creditee_type_desc varchar(30) null,
    creditee_no int null, 
    creditee_name varchar(80) null
    )

Create index aaa on #transactions(customer_no, fund_no)

Insert  into #transactions (sequence_no, trn_type, fund_no, fyear, campaign_no, campaign, cont_designation_id, batch_no, posted_ind, ref_no, 
        cont_dt, trn_dt, pledge, pledge_payment, gift, restricted, write_off, total_received, channel, customer_no)
Select  a.sequence_no,
    a.trn_type,
    a.fund_no,
    cm.fyear,
    a.campaign_no,
    cm.description,
    Coalesce(d.cont_designation, 0),        -- Default no designation to 0
    a.batch_no,
    Case When a.posted_status = 'Y' Then 1 Else 0 End,
    a.ref_no,
    d.cont_dt,
    a.trn_dt,
    pledge = CASE WHEN trn_type in (2, 5) THEN a.trn_amt ELSE 0 END,
    pledge_payment = CASE WHEN trn_type in (3, 6) THEN a.trn_amt ELSE 0 END,
    gift = CASE WHEN trn_type in (1, 4, 61) THEN a.trn_amt ELSE 0 END,
    restricted = CASE WHEN trn_type = 10 THEN a.trn_amt
                    When trn_type = 11 Then a.trn_amt * -1
                    Else 0 End,
    write_off = CASE WHEN trn_type in (7) THEN a.trn_amt ELSE 0 END, 
    total_received = CASE WHEN trn_type in (1, 3, 4, 6, 61) THEN trn_amt ELSE 0 END,
    channel = e.id,
    customer_no = d.customer_no
from    [dbo].t_transaction a 
    JOIN @fund b ON a.fund_no = b.fund_no
    LEFT JOIN dbo.FT_SPLIT_LIST(@appeal_str, ',') ap on a.appeal_no = ap.element
    JOIN [dbo].T_CONTRIBUTION d ON a.ref_no = d.ref_no
    JOIN dbo.T_BATCH ba on a.batch_no = ba.batch_no
    JOIN dbo.T_CAMPAIGN cm on d.campaign_no = cm.campaign_no
    JOIN @cont_designation cd on d.cont_designation = cd.id or (d.cont_designation is NULL and cd.id = 0)
    JOIN @channel e ON d.channel = e.id
where   a.trn_type in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 61)  
    and (Coalesce(@trans_start_dt, @trans_end_dt, null) is NULL or a.trn_dt between @trans_start_dt  and @trans_end_dt) --FP1675.  handling null trans date parameters
    and d.cont_dt between Coalesce(@cont_start_dt, '1900-01-01') and Coalesce(@cont_end_dt, '2999-12-31')
    and (@filter_by_posting_date = 0 or ba.posted_dt between @posting_start_dt and @posting_end_dt)
    and (@appeal_str is NULL or ap.ElementId > 0)


If @campaign_str is NOT NULL
    Delete From #transactions 
    Where campaign_no NOT IN (Select element From dbo.FT_SPLIT_LIST(@campaign_str, ','))

If @mode = 3 -- Payment (includes gift change transaction amounts where no payment method is involved)
  Begin
    Insert into #transactions (sequence_no, trn_type, fund_no, fyear, campaign_no, campaign, cont_designation_id, batch_no, posted_ind, ref_no, 
        cont_dt, trn_dt, pledge, pledge_payment, gift, restricted, write_off, total_received, 
        channel, customer_no, pmt_method_id, pmt_method, pledge_pmt_amt, gift_pmt_amt)
    Select t.sequence_no,
            t.trn_type,
            t.fund_no,
            t.fyear,
            t.campaign_no,
            t.campaign,
            t.cont_designation_id,
            t.batch_no,
            t.posted_ind,
            t.ref_no,
            t.cont_dt,
            t.trn_dt,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            t.channel,
            t.customer_no,
            Coalesce(p.pmt_method, -1),
            Coalesce(pm.description, '(Gift Change)'),
            Case When t.trn_type in (3,6) Then Coalesce(p.pmt_amt, t.total_received) Else 0 End,
            Case When t.trn_type in (1,4,61) Then Coalesce(p.pmt_amt, t.total_received) Else 0 End
    From #transactions t
        LEFT JOIN dbo.T_PAYMENT p on t.sequence_no = p.sequence_no
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TR_PAYMENT_METHOD pm on p.pmt_method = pm.id
    Where t.trn_type in (1, 3, 4, 6, 61)
  End


If @list_no > 0
  Begin
    If @list_acts_upon = 1
      Begin
        Delete From #transactions
        Where customer_no not in (Select customer_no From dbo.T_LIST_CONTENTS Where list_no = @list_no)
      End
    Else
      Begin
        Delete  a
        From    #transactions a
            JOIN T_CONTRIBUTION b ON a.ref_no = b.ref_no
        Where   (b.initiator_no is not null and b.initiator_no not in (Select customer_no From dbo.T_LIST_CONTENTS Where list_no = @list_no))
            OR
            (b.initiator_no is null and b.customer_no not in (Select customer_no From dbo.T_LIST_CONTENTS Where list_no = @list_no))

      End
  End




If @show_constituent_detail = 'Y'
  Begin
    Update a    -- If more than ONE creditee per contribution, the selection here is 1-1 and arbitrary (well, based on page file)
    Set creditee_no = b.creditee_no,
        creditee_type = c.id,
        creditee_type_desc = c.descriptiuon,
        creditee_name = dn.display_name
    From    #transactions a
        JOIN dbo.T_CREDITEE b ON a.ref_no = b.ref_no
        JOIN dbo.TR_CREDITEE_TYPE c ON b.creditee_type = c.id
        JOIN dbo.FT_CONSTITUENT_DISPLAY_NAME() dn on b.creditee_no = dn.customer_no
  End


If @fyear_str is NOT NULL
  Begin
    Delete From #transactions
    Where fyear NOT IN (Select element From dbo.FT_SPLIT_LIST(@fyear_str, ','))
  End

If @mode in (1,3)
    Update #transactions
    Set fyear = null,
        campaign_no = null,
        campaign = NULL,
        cont_designation_id = null

If @show_constituent_detail = 'Y'
    Select  trn_count = Case When a.pmt_method_id is NOT NULL Then 0 Else 1 End,        
            a.pledge,
            a.pledge_payment,
            a.gift,
            a.restricted,
            a.write_off,
            a.total_received,
            a.batch_no,
            a.ref_no,
            a.cont_dt,
            a.trn_dt,
            fund_no = a.fund_no,
            fund_desc = f.fund_desc,
            a.fyear,
            a.campaign_no,
            a.campaign,
            a.cont_designation_id,
            cont_designation = d.description,
            channel_id = a.channel,
            channel_desc = ch.description,
            a.pmt_method_id,
            a.pmt_method,           
            a.pledge_pmt_amt,
            a.gift_pmt_amt,
            pmt_count = case When a.pmt_method_id is NOT NULL Then 1 Else 0 End,
            c.customer_no,
            c.lname,
            c.fname,
            a.creditee_type,
            a.creditee_type_desc,
            a.creditee_no,
            a.creditee_name,
            dn.display_name,
            dn.sort_name
    From #transactions a
        JOIN @fund f on a.fund_no = f.fund_no
        LEFT JOIN @channel ch on a.channel = ch.id
        LEFT JOIN @cont_designation d on a.cont_designation_id = d.id
        LEFT JOIN dbo.T_CUSTOMER c on a.customer_no = c.customer_no
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FT_CONSTITUENT_DISPLAY_NAME() dn on c.customer_no = dn.customer_no
Else
    Select  trn_count = SUM(Case When a.pmt_method_id is NOT NULL Then 0 Else 1 End),       
            pledge = sum(a.pledge),
            pledge_payment = sum(a.pledge_payment),
            gift = sum(a.gift),
            restricted = sum(a.restricted),
            write_off = sum(a.write_off),
            total_received = sum(a.total_received),
            batch_no = null,
            ref_no = null,
            cont_dt = null,
            trn_dt = null,
            fund_no = a.fund_no,
            fund_desc = max(f.fund_desc),
            a.fyear,
            a.campaign_no,
            campaign = MAX(a.campaign),
            a.cont_designation_id,
            cont_desisgnation = max(d.description),
            channel_id = null,
            channel_desc = null,
            a.pmt_method_id,
            pmt_method = MAX(a.pmt_method),
            pledge_pmt_amt = SUM(a.pledge_pmt_amt),
            gift_pmt_amt = SUM(a.gift_pmt_amt),
            pmt_count = SUM(case When a.pmt_method_id is NOT NULL Then 1 Else 0 End),
            customer_no = null,
            lname = null,
            fname = null,
            creditee_type = null,
            creditee_type_desc = null,
            creditee_no = null,
            creditee_name = null,
            display_name = null,
            sort_name = null
    From #transactions a
        JOIN @fund f on a.fund_no = f.fund_no
        LEFT JOIN @cont_designation d on a.cont_designation_id = d.id
    Group by a.fyear, a.campaign_no, a.fund_no, a.cont_designation_id, a.pmt_method_id
RETURN
```

---

The table I need to add is a simple Local Table titled ISTA_VARIANCE_GOALS and it only needs to reflect the proj_amt (GOAL) to SUM from.  It has proj_amt, fund_no, campaign_no, but I really think all I need is the proj_amt.

And that's it.
But I cannot seem to make it work.
And it driving me c-r-a-z-y.****

Comment: I would suggest try with the simplest short SP that you can test. and work your way up . adding pieces to make them as big as what you post above. I am sure you will find the problem.